# How to debug a concurrency problem in Java FX?

Tags: java, javafx, concurrency

I'm programming my first app with concurrency and I have a bug that I can't understand. The program is supposed to read a buffer and if there is a message print something in a console made with a TextArea. The problem is that it prints the message in console twice.

I have a hint that the problem resides in concurrency, as I have the same program without it and it works fine. The bug is in the message I marked **This message*.

```
public void ReadTask()
{
    Runnable task=() -> {
        runReadTask();
    };
Thread backgroundThread =new Thread(task);
backgroundThread.setDaemon(true);
backgroundThread.start();
}

public void runReadTask()
{
    int contador=0;
    while(true)
    {
        if(ComprobarBuffer(msg,can)==true)
        {
            contador=contador+1;
            final String cont="Mensaje " +contador;
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                consola.appendText(cont+" Se ha leido un mensaje\n"); //**This message**
            });

        }
    }
```

}

```
public static boolean ComprobarBuffer(TPCANMsg msg,PCANBasic can)
{
boolean lectura;
if (can.Read(TPCANHandle.PCAN_USBBUS1, msg,null)==TPCANStatus.PCAN_ERROR_OK) 
{
lectura=true;
} else {
lectura=false;
}
return lectura;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: A specific hardware is needed in order the program to work. The only thing it has is a button, and when the button is pressed it calls the ReadTask function that is supposed to work in an infinite loop, that's why i'm trying to create a new thread, to leave the GUI and the event handling in the main thread.

Comment: if you can't make it reproducible for us, then you are on your own - no way we can help you. Be sure to update the ui on the fx application thread ...

Comment: ohh .. and please learn java naming conventions and stick to them (unrelated to your problem, though :)

Comment: What is `PCANBasic`? What does it guarantee in terms of concurrency / consistency? Do you have a link to the JavaDoc?

Comment: PCANBasic is a class provided by an API of the specific software I commented

Comment: https://www.peak-system.com/PCAN-Basic.239.0.html?L=1

Comment: Here it says it is "Thread-safe"

Comment: I would start by using `System.out.println()` to make sure I am receiving the data.

Comment: The issue is unlikely to be related to javafx. You've probably already verified `ReadTask()` is called only once by checking the numbers in the output. You should be able to reproduce the same issue without JavaFX. In that case no concurrency should be involved unless you access the resources from a different thread.